# Django reverse and url default instead of NoReverseMatch

Tags: django

Is it possible to set up a default URL which will be used whenever a reverse match cannot be found? The idea is that if in production there is a typo, I would like to display something akin to a 404 or a descriptive error page, instead of getting a NoReverseMatch exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templatetag url raise a Exception. You can see in the code:

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/templatetags/future.py#L117

But, you can create other templatetag (copy and paste 90%), that does not raise anything and "display something akin to a 404 or a descriptive error page, instead of getting a NoReverseMatch exception."

Answer (score 1):

i guess you could catch the exception and choose your detault url

```
try:
    url = reverse('missing')
except NoReverseMatch:
    url = default
```

Comment: not sure, i guess you may be stuck writing a custom template tag. check the implementation of `{% url %}` and add the try catch