# Should Django reverse exceptions yield a 404 or 500?

Tags: django, http

I contemplating whether or not to catch all Django reverse exceptions and raise 404s  instead of 500s.

This question is akin to:
[Django reverse and url default instead of NoReverseMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433424/django-reverse-and-url-default-instead-of-noreversematch)

For example, if I have an authentication app which mimics Django's native login decorator. If a view is decorated an the user is not authenticated, they are first redirected to the login page.

I have a reverse('login') call within the decorator. Let's say I decided to change the url name provided in my urlsconf to 'my_login' but unintentionally forget to update my decorator.

Should this be a 404 or a 500 error? I would lean towards a 500 as there is no reasonable fall-back to handle the exception. The redirect is internal and the resource does exists I just made 'typo' of sorts.

try/excepting each reverse call seems to be walking a fine line towards catching NameErrors and SyntaxErrors.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why isn't your unit testing catching the reverse failures?

Comment: Agreed. Testing should be sufficient. Thanks very much

Answer (score 4):

404 is for when a *client*-requested  resource is not found. Since reversing is a *server* operation, a 5XX response would be appropriate.